# What are counters of the anthropic principle

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, ontology

The anthropic principle states that observations of the Universe must be compatible with the conscious and sapient life that observes it. Some people say that it explains why this universe has the age and the fundamental physical constants necessary to accommodate conscious life.

Are there any famous counters to this theory

Suggestions about texts and articles to read on the topic are welcome.

Comment: Wikipedia article on anthropic principle has a long [section on criticisms of it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropic_principle#Reception_and_controversies), which includes a number of references.

Comment: I would recommend [The Cosmic Landscape: String Theory and the Illusion of Intelligent Design](https://www.amazon.com/Cosmic-Landscape-String-Illusion-Intelligent/dp/0316013331) by Leonard Susskind. In this book he tackles the idea of anthropic principle.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6738/is-the-anthropic-principle-in-physics-falsifiable?rq=1)

Comment: Any non-dualistic philosophy or science (i.e. that is not presupposing the old Cartesian divide of res extensa and res cogitans or material and consciousness) has to argue against an underlying Idealism á la pre-stabilisation (Leibniz, ontologising) or constructivism (neo-Kantians). Philosophy and science of life argues in this direction, being caught in methodological struggles I found most clearly worked out in Hellmuth Plessners "Die Stufen des Organischen und der Mensch" (*The Levels of the Organic and the Human*, translation available early 2018 - hopefully)

Comment: I don't think that there is any strong arguments against it, its more or less a tautology.